# SQL - How to average by group for a single column?

Tags: sql, group-by, grouping, average

I'm trying to get my query to average one column across WO groupings so I can get rid of duplicates that are affecting a calculation in another column. A little background - In this dataset, a work order can have one or multiple check in/outs combinations. The travel/prep time is recorded at the WO level however I need my data at the more granular level of individual check in/out combination.

The issue I'm having is that the travel time repeats for each check in/out combination for the work order which overstates the actual time. I'm hoping someone can help me figure out how a) either average the travel time across the group or b) change the duplicate instances to Null or zero so I can get accurate times. In the example in the link attached, you can see that work order 'PGE083300001' is double counting the travel time for those two different check in/out combinations. 7.5 hrs is the total time for the work order but the column should show that spread across the two entries as 3.75 each.

Here is the SQL statement:

```
SELECT
a.WorkOrderCustomID, 
b.[Work Order #],
b.[checkIn Date],
b.[checkOut Date],
CONVERT(decimal (16,2),[Windshield/Travel/Prep Time (Hours)]) AS TravelPrepAvg
    FROM clientssdv.vw_Corrigo_WorkOrder_Custom a
     INNER JOIN ssdv.vw_Corrigo_vbiWorkOrderCheckInOuts b on a.WorkOrderCustomID = b.[Work Order ID]
     INNER JOIN ssdv.vw_Corrigo_vbiWorkOrders c ON b.[Work Order ID] = c.ID
        WHERE Status <> 'Cancelled'
          ORDER BY [Work Order ID]
```

[[image: travel prep example]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not images (nor links to images.) And simplify if possible - [mcve].

Comment: Wow, why should the 7.5 be split evenly over the two entries? You need to show us the values for `Windshield`, `Travel` and `Prep Time (hours)` while we can speculate here, having the raw inputs to your equation will help

Comment: I’ll keep that in mind for next time. I was able to solve this issue by using the lag function and turning the duplicates to null. Appreciate the responses tho.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is a cleaner way, but without more detail on your schema we can only theorise. So even though I don't think it is the best solution to your problem, when data isn't quite in the form we need in MS SQL Server (since 2012) you can use most standard aggregates over windowed queries. This technique is commonly used to calculate running totals or rolling averages.

Take a fictious set of data created from your screenshot:

| WO# | TimeWorked | Windshield |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PGE1264 | 0.1 | NULL |
| PGE1110 | 0.25 | NULL |
| PGE2458 | 0.4 | NULL |
| PGE2459 | 0.97 | 4 |
| PGE2459 | 0.18 | 2 |
| PGE0833 | 0.0 | 7.5 |
| PGE0833 | 0.02 | 7.5 |
| PGE0870 | 0.02 | NULL |

We can query this set is two ways, either to produce a single record for each `WO` or to normalise the values across the range.

*notice I have injected some other values for PGE2459 to prove the point*

```
DECLARE @data as Table
(
    [WO] char(12),
    TimeWorked NUMERIC(10,2),
    Windsheild NUMERIC(10,2) NULL
)
INSERT INTO @data ([WO],TimeWorked,Windsheild)
VALUES
('PGE1264',0.1  ,NULL),
('PGE1110',0.25 ,NULL),
('PGE2458',0.4  ,NULL),
('PGE2459',0.97 ,4 ),
('PGE2459',0.18 ,2 ),
('PGE0833',0.0  ,7.5 ),
('PGE0833',0.02 ,7.5 ),
('PGE0870',0.02 ,NULL)

SELECT [WO], AVG(Windsheild)
FROM @data
GROUP BY [WO]

SELECT [WO], AVG(Windsheild) OVER (PARTITION BY [WO]) / COUNT(Windsheild) OVER  (PARTITION BY [WO])
FROM @data
```

Using a simple `GROUP BY`, table 1 has been reduced to only a single record for each `WO` this is generally the easiest form to join on:

| WO |  |
| --- | --- |
| PGE0833 | 7.500000 |
| PGE0870 | NULL |
| PGE1110 | NULL |
| PGE1264 | NULL |
| PGE2458 | NULL |
| PGE2459 | 3.000000 |

If you can't group across the entire set, then you can still use [Window Functions](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9124/sql-server-window-aggregate-functions-sum-min-max-and-avg/) to evaluate the aggregates inline, the results of the second query:

| WO |  |
| --- | --- |
| PGE0833 | 3.750000 |
| PGE0833 | 3.750000 |
| PGE0870 | NULL |
| PGE1110 | NULL |
| PGE1264 | NULL |
| PGE2458 | NULL |
| PGE2459 | 1.500000 |
| PGE2459 | 1.500000 |

Notice how in this query, we can obtain the Average across all rows and then return the values evenly distributed acorss the affected rows, in this way `SUM`,`COUNT`,`AVG` aggregates over the resulting set will still return the same values as the original query.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I actually went with option B in my post and was able to find another stackflow post that had some applicable code. The use of the Lag Function was what solved the issue. I'll post my answer in just a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

**Code Fixed**

I was able to find another post that showed a similar code using the lag function to turn everything null after the first entry. I'm only going to post the relevant portion of the field I needed to change in case any of you are curious.

```
CASE
            WHEN CONVERT(decimal (16,2),[Windshield/Travel/Prep Time (Hours)]) = LAG(CONVERT(decimal (16,2),[Windshield/Travel/Prep Time (Hours)]),1,NULL)
            OVER 
                (ORDER BY b.[Work Order ID], a.[WO#], b.[CheckIn Date]) THEN NULL ELSE CONVERT(decimal (16,2),[Windshield/Travel/Prep Time (Hours)])
        END AS Windshield_TravelPrepTime_hrs
```

Here's the new, correct output:

```
 WO#           CheckIn Date   CheckOut Date TimeWorked  Windshield_TravelPrepTime_hrs
PGE088000171    18:00.0       30:00.0         2.2          -84.5
PGE088000171    06:00.0       57:00.0         1.85          NULL
PGE088000171    39:00.0       30:00.0         2.85          NULL
PGE088000171    28:00.0       04:00.0         1.6           NULL
```

This was my first post so I'm glad some people reached out. Thanks again!

Comment: You may have found a workaround, but to be honest I believe that is you supplied raw data from each of the 3 tables (just a tiny set of samples, but they have to "work" in the original query including the joins) then a more efficient method is likely be available, my guess if you used s subquery on `ssdv.vw_Corrigo_vbiWorkOrderCheckInOuts` before joining you may avoid the repetition (that you call duplicates).